# how to get data from dynamic object using loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net, nuget-package

how to get value from Dynamic object and add something and return into Json format ... how to get data from This Dynamic object and show into richtextbox
please help me

> JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
>               dynamic item = serializer.Deserialize(patch.ToString());

```
using JsonDiffPatchDotNet;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
ad.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; )
    {
        string JsonValue = dt.Rows[i]["History"].ToString();
        string GetDate = dt.Rows[i]["ActivityTimeStamp"].ToString();
        string JsonValue2 = dt.Rows[++i]["History"].ToString();
        var jdp = new JsonDiffPatch();
        var left = JToken.Parse(JsonValue);
        var right = JToken.Parse(JsonValue2);

        JToken patch = jdp.Diff(left, right);
         JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        dynamic item = serializer.Deserialize<object>(patch.ToString());

        re = new Regex("[[{;\\\\/*?<>|&}]");
        string outputString = re.Replace(patch.ToString(), " ");
        outputString = outputString.Replace(']', ' ');
        txtresult.Text += "---" + GetDate + "----"
                                + dt.Rows[i]["ActivityTimeStamp"].ToString()
                                + "---\n\n";
        txtresult.Text += outputString;
        txtresult.Text += "\n";


        txtresult.Text += "---------------------------\n\n";
    }
}
```

[image]

i want like this for show data
[image]